# SharePoint file can be opened with VBA but cannot check if it exists using Dir("https://....xlsx")

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a program within which I want to check if a number of files exist before attempting operations on them (which take a while). I am currently using a function to check the workbook exists:

```
Function WorkbookExists(FileName As String)
 If Len(Dir(FileName)) > 0 Then
  WorkbookExists = True
 Else
  WorkbookExists = False
End Function
```

Which works for local adresses i.e. "C:\Users\abcdef\sample.xlsx" returns "True" and I then open that file with `Workbooks.Open(FileName)` without issue.

But when I do the same with a Sharepoint file:

`WorkbookExists("https://blah-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user/sample.xlsx")`

It fails specifically on `Dir(FileName)` with a "Run-time error 52: Bad file name or number"

The file opens perfectly well with `Workbooks.Open(FileName)` however.

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of Dir() and whether an alternative to checking whether a file exists? My computer has all files under the SharePoint site, so a "ThisWorkbook.Path" returns the SharePoint address also.

I expected the function to return true as the file exists.

Comment: The Dir() doesn't work with URLs or network paths, check below link:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-to-check-if-file-exists-on-sharepoint.570437/

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to sync the folder to your local PC and then work on the local copy.