Save file with new name if file already exists
I created a UserForm where my team can select the type of report they need, "Condizione di Pericolo" / "Mancato Infortunio" / "Infortunio".
This selection is stored in the variable evento.
After that, I want the file to create and save a copy of the report in a folder based on the report selected.
In SharePoint I have folders "Condizione di Pericolo" / "Mancato Infortunio" / "Infortunio".
The name of the file is standard and based on the date and the name of the user.
There is the possibility that someone makes the same report twice or more in the same day.
I don't want anything to be overwritten, that is why I'm trying to check if in the correct folder there is a file with the same name. If there is, I want the new one to add a suffix like (1) (just like when we make a copy of a file).
Sub SaveReport()

    Const path As String = "https://SharePointPath/Main%20Folder/"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Saved As Boolean
    
    i = 1
    Saved = False
    evento = "Condizione di Pericolo"   ' Just to test the code

    Sheets("Modulo19").Activate         ' Redondant, now I know!
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    
    If evento = "Condizione di Pericolo" Then
        ' filename = path + nome del file + estensione
        filename = path & "/" & "Condizione%20di%20Pericolo" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & ".xlsx"
        
        ' Check to see if the file exist
        If Len(Dir(filename)) = "" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Call GeneraReport
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
        
        ' If it exist, let's use another name
        Do While Saved = False
            If Len(Dir(filename)) <> "" Then
                filename = path & "/" & "Condizione%20di%20Pericolo" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & "_(" & i & ")" & ".xlsx"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                Saved = True
                Call GeneraReport
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
        

    ' From now on is just the same code repeating...

    ElseIf evento = "Mancato Infortunio" Then
        filename = path & "/" & "Mancato%20Infortunio" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & ".xlsx"
        
        If FileExist(filename) = False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Call GeneraReport
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
        
        Do While Saved = False
            If FileExist(filename) = False Then
                filename = path & "/" & "Mancato%20Infortunio" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & "_(" & i & ")" & ".xlsx"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                Saved = True
                Call GeneraReport
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop

        
    ElseIf evento = "Infortunio" Then
        filename = path & "/" & "Infortunio" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & ".xlsx"
        
        If FileExist(filename) = False Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Call GeneraReport
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
        
        Do While Saved = False
            If FileExist(filename) = False Then
                filename = path & "/" & "Infortunio" & "/" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & "_(" & i & ")" & ".xlsx"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                Saved = True
                Call GeneraReport
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
      
    End If
    
End Sub

The forward slash / is not a problem for the SaveAs command. I use it in other files.
Right now, I have the problem with the Dir command.
I have this error:

Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number
I also use this Function called FileExist found on the internet.
Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean
'PURPOSE: Test to see if a file exists or not
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim TestStr As String

'Test File Path (ie "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Test\book1.xlsm")
  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if File exists
  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If

End Function

In this case I always get Empty as result, so for the Function I do not have a file with the same name and it overwrites it.

Dir will not work properly when you use it recursively. Use a FileSystemObject instead.

"Not working" doesn't tell us much about the exact problem you're having?

Add Debug.Print filename before the SaveAs - does the output (in the Immediate pane in the VB editor) look correct?

I've edited (re-written is a better word!) all the question, 'cause it was not clear... I'm sorry!

@TimWilliams how can I have that panel? I don't have it open... Note that I'm not a pro user ^^'

Press Ctrl+G in the VB editor or View menu >> Immediate window

@TimWilliams - Yes, the output is correct:
https: //SharePointPath/Main%20Folder/Condizione%20di%20Pericolo/22-07-2024_NAME.xlsx

Dir doesn't work with http paths, only local or networked folder paths...   You would need to sync the folder to your local PC to use Dir.

@TimWilliams a little clarification: I can't put Debug.Print filename right before the SaveAs-Command, because I have the error on the Len(Dir(filename)) line...

@TimWilliams Oh... Now I understand... There is a way for http paths?

Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77360777/sharepoint-file-can-be-opened-with-vba-but-cannot-check-if-it-exists-using-dir   Basically try to open the file and see if it works...  Likely would be Ok if a little slow.

(Previous response from when we were discussing local paths...)
Here's a simpler version (edit: per FunThomas's answer, forward slashes should be backslashes):
Sub SalvaReport()

    Const path As String = "C:\SharePointDirectory\SharePoint%20Folder\"
    Dim i As Long, fnTemplate As String, fldr As String, fileName As String, evento As String
    
    i = 0
    evento = "Condizione di Pericolo"  ' etc
    fldr = Replace(evento, " ", "%20") 'replace spaces with %20
    
    'File name template: `{tmp}` is a token to be replaced...
    fnTemplate = path & "\" & fldr & "\" & _
                Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & _
                Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1) & "{tmp}.xlsx"
                
    fileName = Replace(fnTemplate, "{tmp}", "") 'start with no counter
    Do While Len(Dir(fileName, vbNormal)) = 0   'file exists?
        i = i + 1
        fileName = Replace(fnTemplate, "{tmp}", "(" & i & ")") 'add counter
    Loop
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Modulo19").Copy  ' Copio l'intera sheets "Modulo19"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    GeneraReport 'no need for `Call`
         
End Sub

Added after it was clear you're looking for something to check for files over HTTP[S] (where Dir() won't work)...
You can use ADO to query a SharePoint List/Library - see example code below.  You could use this as a basis for finding if a given filename already exists.
Sub ListSPLibraryFiles()
    '## Add a VBA project reference to the ADO object library ##
    Const SERVERUrl As String = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ABCSite/"
    Const ListName As String = "{f82ace17-b0c2-48b4-aa1c-b5d93ddb0c35}" 'List/Library *GUID*
    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String, objWksheet As Worksheet
    
    With Conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                             "DATABASE=" & SERVERUrl & ";" & _
                             "LIST=" & ListName & ";"
        .Open ' Open the connection
    End With
     
    'query all library records for xlsx docs
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [" & ListName & "] where [Content Type]='Document' and [File Type]='xlsx'"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, Conn, adOpenStatic
    
    PutToSheet rs, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results") 'display the results
    
    rs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Sub

'load field names and data from `rs` to worksheet `ws`
Sub PutToSheet(rs As ADODB.Recordset, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim f As ADODB.Field, i As Long
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear 'clear any previous data
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            For Each f In rs.Fields
                ws.Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value = f.Name
                i = i + 1
            Next f
            ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Check out what shows up on the "results" sheet and figure out how to use that info to confirm a given path.

As I told to FunThomas, i have other files where the slashes "/" are working fine... Anyway, i'll try your solutions!

If you told us what the actual problem is that might help you get to a solution.

You're totally right, I made a very bad-written question. I've edited it right now!

Edited to add a possible route for checking if a file exists in a SharePoint library.

As far as I see, the problem you have is related to that you are working on Windows but uses the slash (/) instead of the backslash (\) as path separator. The Dir command will work with both, but the SaveAs-command fails.
I came up with the following code. The variable basename will contain the base name of the file while filename will contain the name including the number and the extension.
Note that you don't need to activate a sheet to copy it.
Sub SalvaReport()
    Const path As String = "C:\SharePointDirectory\SharePoint%20Folder\"
    
    Dim basename As String, filename As String, username As String
    username = Split(Application.UserName, " ")(1)
    basename = path & "Condizione%20di%20Pericolo" & "\" & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy") & "_" & username
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 100
        filename = basename & IIf(i = 0, "", "(" & i & ")") & ".xlsx"
        If Dir(filename) = "" Then
            Sheets("Modulo19").Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            Call GeneraReport
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "No free filenumber found, maybe you need to clean up a little bit..."
End Sub


Good catch on the forward slash...

Hi! I can tell for sure that the SaveAs-command work fine with the slash "/", 'cause I use them in a lot other files... Also, if I use the Copy Path button in the SP-excel it uses the slashes "/"... I'll try this code!
